# slice a list based on some values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I'm looking for a way to split a list based on some values, and assuming the list's length equals to sum of some values, e.g.:

list: `l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`
values: `v = (1,1,2,2)`
so `len(l) = sum(v)`

and I'd like to have a  function to return a tuple or a list, like: `(['a'], ['b'], ['c','d'], ['d','e'])`

currently my code is like:

```
(list1,list2,list3,list4) = (
    l[0:v[0]], 
    l[v[0]:v[0]+v[1]], 
    l[v[0]+v[1]:v[0]+v[1]+v[2]], 
    l[v[0]+v[1]+v[2]:v[0]+v[1]+v[2]+v[3]])`
```

I'm thinking about make this clearer, but closest one I have so far is (note the results are incorrect, not what I wanted)

```
s=0
[list1,list2,list3,list4] = [l[s:s+i] for i in v]
```

the problem is I couldn't increase `s` at the same time while iterating values in `v`, I'm hoping to get a better code to do so, any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe make a generator of the values in l?

```
def make_list(l, v):
    g = (x for x in l)
    if len(l) == sum(v):
       return [[next(g) for _ in range(val)] for val in v]
    return None
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I thought about list.popleft() and pop up the number of items I need, but this achieves the same thing for me!

Comment: FYI, it's far more direct to convert `l` to an iterator with  `g = iter(l)`. That adds no per-item overhead, where making a generator expression adds per-item overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If you weren't stuck on ancient Python, I'd point you to [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). Of course, even on ancient Python, you could use the (roughly) equivalent code provided in the docs I linked to do it. Using either the Py3 code or equivalent, you could do:

```
from itertools import accumulate  # Or copy accumulate equivalent Python code
from itertools import chain

# Calls could be inlined in listcomp, but easier to read here
starts = accumulate(chain((0,), v))  # Extra value from starts ignored when ends exhausted
ends = accumulate(v)
list1,list2,list3,list4 = [l[s:e] for s, e in zip(starts, ends)]
```

Comment: This is great! Our entire project is based on python 2.7, that's why I put python-2.7 tag, but still thanks so much for your answer, definitely what i'm looking for, will see if I can get equivalent codes for python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a simple loop to iterate over `v` to generate a result:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
v = (1,1,2,2)
result = []
offset = 0

for size in v:
    result.append(l[offset:offset+size])
    offset += size

print result
```

Output:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is using a nested loop. Assuming that your condition will always holds true, the logic then is to run through `v` and pick up `i` elements from `l` where `i` is an number from `v`.

```
index = 0 # this is the start index
for num in v:
    temp = [] # this is a temp array, to hold individual elements in your result array.
    for j in range(index, index+num): # this loop will pickup the next num elements from l
        temp.append(l[j])
    data.append(temp)
    index += num
```

Output:
`[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]`

The first answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715361/5759063 is the most pythonic way to do it. This is just the algorithmic backbone.

Comment: Thanks! yes I'm aware of the algorithmic backbone, if I could increase the index then I can get the sublists.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could find is a two line solution:

```
breaks=[0]+[sum(v[:i+1]) for i in range(len(v))]  #build a list of section indices
result=[l[breaks[i]:breaks[i+1]] for i in range(len(breaks)-1)]  #split array according to indices
print result
```